# How to make objects flying around in a view

Tags: iphone, object, accelerometer, shake

How is it possible to let some objects fly around and bumb at the end of the view and collide on each other.

The second step would add acceleration of the objects by shaking.

I haven't found a tutorial yet or some step to begin at.

thanks a lot for your help :)

Heres a picter of what i image(only a still)

http://picfront.org/d/ZdSvK9G8D/flying_circles.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Cocos2d for iPhone](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/about). Google will help you find many tutorials for this framework.

Comment: great, thanks a lot for that great framework and of course cour help :)
Do you know any other great and usefull frameworks for iphone coding?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to search for are tutorials on "Collision Detection." Cocos2D is a great place but you will also need a physics engine - Box2d and Chipmunk are both physics libraries that can be used. Some good videos on youtube for cocos2d tutorials and physics engines to see if this is what you are looking for.

Matthew